# Vertex paint texture not visible in cycle render view

Tags: vertex-paint

when I use vertex paint to blend two textures I can only see the effect of the painting in the material preview mode but when I switch it to rendered view painted texture does not appear. This only happens in Cycles.

I followed this tutorial step by step:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccciTF5aZP8&t=1089s

My node seems to work ok because I can blend to textures in the material preview mode.
I do not want to bake two textures together. I would like to just use paint vertex tool.

I use mix shader node based on rgb.

How can I make it visible in rendered view?

Material preview:

[image]

Cycles rendered view:
[image]

Node:

[image]

Comment: Hard to see but it looks like there is no Vertex color layer specified in the vertex colors node

Comment: it's very hard to read your screenshot, you need to use an Input > Attribute node and type the vertex color group name in

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am newbie here so I apologize for screen shots quality. I the tutorial he did not use an attribute node but I suppose it works more or less the same. Long and short - problem was that vertex color node has that little drop down box where layer needs to be selected. After I selected the layer everything works perfectly. Thanks for the replies!